# replace-regexp-in-string: How to prepend a string to the entire string matched?

Tags: regular-expressions, replace

I am adding divider lines to certain sections of the reports generated by the binary `ledger` [ https://www.ledger-cli.org/ ] through the function `ledger-do-report` in the `ledger-mode` Lisp library [ https://github.com/ledger/ledger-mode].  To accomplish this goal, I have chosen `replace-regexp-in-string`.  I wish to **prepend** the divider line followed by a new line; i.e., `"======\n"`.

**Q**:  Is there a built-in way to prepend the additional string without the need to create an empty substring at the beginning of the REGEXP; i.e., `\\(\\)`?

In the following example, I have begun my REGEXP with `^\\(\\)` so that I can replace that number 1 subsexpression with the new string.  However, I have a feeling that there is a more correct approach to simply prepend a string without using an empty placeholder in the REGEXP.

NOTE:  The `^[` is defined by Emacs as:    old-name: ESCAPE; general-category: Cc (Other, Control); decomposition: (27) ('^[')

```lisp
;;;           $ 98,477.47  ASSETS
;;;  =>
;;;
;;;           $ 98,477.47  ^[[34mASSETS^[[0m
;;;
(setq report (replace-regexp-in-string
               "^\\(\\)[\s]+$[\s]\\([0-9,.]+\\)[\s]+^[\\[34m\\(ASSETS\\)^[\\[0m$"
               (concat (make-string (- (window-width) 1) ?=)" \n")
               report nil nil 1))
```

Comment: Note that you can use `"\e"` for the ESCAPE char, and then people can copy/paste the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `LITERAL` is `nil` then you can use `"\\&"` in the replacement to represent the entire matched string, and so your replacement text could be `"PREFIX\\&"`.

Refer to `C-h f replace-match` for the behaviour of `LITERAL`.

(And if you *didn't* want special characters in the replacement text to be processed, you would generally want LITERAL to be non-nil, for safety.)

Comment: Thank you.  I used your answer; and I removed the empty REGEXP subexpression of `\\(\\)`; and I changed SUBEXP so that it is now `nil`; and I added a START of `0`.